# Error while adding Attribute in Magento 1.4.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have started working on a fresh Magento 1.4.2 installation. When I try to add a new attribute I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setIsPopup() on a non-object in /var/www/projects/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php on line 117

I tried searching in google and found a solution here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/214159/

But that resolves add issue but it causes problem in Modifying a attribute.

I like to know if any better solution is available to this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try reinstalling the package "Mage_All_Latest" with the Magento Connect Manager and make sure, you have set the folder-permissions right.
Ensure that the file magento/var/.htaccess, the directories magento/app/etc, magento/var, and all the directories under magento/media are writable by the web server.

It sounds like there was a problem while your install, so a reinstall of the latest packages maybe solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, I could not find a package by name "Mage_All_Latest" in Magento Connect Manager. Please let me know the URL for the package. Or please send the extension key of the package which I can use in Magento connect Manager.

Comment: The URL for the package is "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest" which you can use from within Magento Connect.

Comment: Hi,I tried the same, it resintalled the package. But the problem remains same. (same error is shown when I tried creating an attribute)